# Bash replaceing string i don't want it to

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list that I want to run a command on so I was testing it first with an echo to make sure it was correct but it printed it out wrong.

```
while read name; do echo $name; done < RandomNames
```

This prints out just this list exactly how I want it but if I put anything after the variable it replaces the start of it.

So if I write

```
while read name; do echo $name; done < RandomNames
```

It will print

```
Rich
Chris 
Zack
```

but if I write

```
while read name; do echo $name t; done < RandomNames
```

it writes

```
 tch
 tris
 tck
```

so it replaces the first two characters with what ever I put after the variable and I have no idea why.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this running your last command. Are you sure this is the source of your bug?

Comment: In the future, try to provide **full** reproduction steps, in this case starting with the creation of the RandomNames file. If you tried to test reproduction steps that started with `printf '%s\n' Rich Chris Zack >RandomNames` and then run your command, you would have noted pretty quickly that it didn't actually reproduce your problem, thus making it clear that the file's contents weren't what you thought they were.

Comment: BTW, `echo $foo` has its own bugs; `echo "$foo"` avoids them. (Look at what happens when `foo='*'` for an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has DOS newlines, so each input line ends with a hidden `$'\r'` character that moves the cursor to the beginning of the line after that line is printed, such that the next character written overwrites the line's first character.

Either use `dos2unix` or a similar tool to convert them to UNIX newlines, or expand `${name%$'\r'}` to trim them.